# Are the radio buttons and text in proper order within a Right-To-Left (rtl) HTML area?

Tags: html, radio-button, right-to-left, bidi

I noticed an issue when using right-to-left-based radio buttons on the same line in HTML. The radio "button" does not line up with the associated text as I would expect; the radio for group 1 is next to the label for group 4, but the other buttons seem to line up as I would expect.  This happens on multiple browsers.

Is this expected behavior?  Would a right-to-left based language person understand this?

You can play with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/6U9fw/

```
<div dir="rtl">
<input name="group" id="group1" type="radio" value="group1" />
<label for="group1">group1</label>
<input name="group" id="group2" type="radio" value="group2" />
<label for="group2">group2</label>
<input name="group" id="group3" type="radio" value="group3" />
<label for="group3">group3</label>
<input name="group" id="group4" type="radio" value="group4" />
<label for="group4">group4</label>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe your code is functioning as expected for proper `rtl`.

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6U9fw/7/). I added `&rlm;` between each `input` tag and its associated text.  It is a workaround for [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=237931), and the result produces what I believe is the expected output.

```
<div dir="rtl">
<input name="group" id="group1" type="radio" value="group1" />&rlm;
<label for="group1">group1</label>
<input name="group" id="group2" type="radio" value="group2" />&rlm;
<label for="group2">group2</label>
<input name="group" id="group3" type="radio" value="group3" />&rlm;
<label for="group3">group3</label>
<input name="group" id="group4" type="radio" value="group4" />&rlm;
<label for="group4">group4</label>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't behave correctly, because your div is rtl, but your labels are in English, which is an ltr language. Using labels in an RTL language such as Hebrew will also solve problem naturally, and in an RTL div you probably want labels in an RTL language anyway.

Here's an example:

```
<div dir="rtl">
<input name="group" id="group1" type="radio" value="group1" />
<label for="group1">קבוצה א</label>
<input name="group" id="group2" type="radio" value="group2" />
<label for="group2">קבוצה ב</label>
<input name="group" id="group3" type="radio" value="group3" />
<label for="group3">קבוצה ג</label>
<input name="group" id="group4" type="radio" value="group4" />
<label for="group4">קבוצה ד</label>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())" value="click" />
```

If you need an RTL div with non-RTL labels, you can also use bidi isolation:

```
<div dir="rtl">
<input name="group" id="group1" type="radio" value="group1" />
<label for="group1" style="unicode-bidi: -moz-isolate; unicode-bidi: -webkit-isolate; unicode-bidi: isolate;">group1</label>
<input name="group" id="group2" type="radio" value="group2" />
<label for="group2" style="unicode-bidi: -moz-isolate; unicode-bidi: -webkit-isolate; unicode-bidi: isolate;">group2</label>
<input name="group" id="group3" type="radio" value="group3" />
<label for="group3" style="unicode-bidi: -moz-isolate; unicode-bidi: -webkit-isolate; unicode-bidi: isolate;">group3</label>
<input name="group" id="group4" type="radio" value="group4" />
<label for="group4" style="unicode-bidi: -moz-isolate; unicode-bidi: -webkit-isolate; unicode-bidi: isolate;">group4</label>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val())" value="click" />
```

Notice the style specifications.

This solution is more elegant than adding an &rlm;, but unfortunately it won't work in Microsoft Internet Explorer.